# How to create a thumbnail that fills a certain area in meteor with CollectionFS and graphicsmagick

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, graphicsmagick

Right now I'm using the code here: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#basic-example
Suppose I want a thumbnail 100x100.

But say my image is 400x200, the code above will produce a thumbnail 100x50.

What I want to happen in this example is for the image to be resized to 200x100, and then clipped to 100x100.
How do I do that? How can I get the height and width?  I know I can use gm's size function, but I can't wrap my head around all the callbacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

`gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).autoOrient().resize('100', '100', "^").gravity('Center').extent('100', '100').stream().pipe(writeStream);`

The `autoOrient()` will automatically turn any mobile-phone photos to the correct direction (otherwise they sometimes come in sideways). The `^` that gets passed to `resize` is an option that makes the "smallest edge" of your image resize to 100.  So this will leave an "overhang" on the "correct" edge.  It takes care of your image being really wide or really tall.  The `extant` then crops your image removing the overhang.  The `gravity('Center')` makes the cropping effect of `extant` occur at the center of the image.

The only the thing I still haven't figured out is how to crop from the center of the image.  According to most examples, calling `gravity('center')` should do this, but it's not working for me. It always crops from the corner.  It's working, it just doesn't look the best as most subject matter is in the center of an image.

EDIT: The `gravity` call needs `'Center'` to work, not `'center'`.  The call now works as intended. Also added `autoOrient()` call.

[Here's the official gm doc](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-geometry) explaining the options. But it took researching how to do this in gm for node.js to figure the above syntax.

Comment: Thanks. That's a big step forward. I don't have a need for this at the moment. What I did is just scale the image with CSS, not an ideal solution, but it works.  I'll test this in my next project, though. Since it's been a while since I posted the question, I'll mark this as correct for now. Hopefully someone can help us with that last piece of the puzzle.  Thanks again.

Comment: I figured out the mistake.  It needed `'Center'` with a capital C.  Now it correctly crops from the center!

Comment: Also just found the `autoOrient()` command to properly orient mobile-phone (and other types) photos.  Thought this would be useful too.

Comment: Great answer, saved me lot's of time. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a TON! You saved my sanity today :D